# SumIf across two sheets

Tags: excel, sumifs, vba

I am trying to do a SumIf where the data is held in Sheet6(Debt) and the sumif needs to be added to Sheet5(Summary - Debt > 12 Months).

I have already gathered unique customer numbers and pasted them into Col B7:B###

The customer Numbers are held in Col B in Debt, and the column to sumif is DebtH:H

To do this in the formula bar I would write: =Sumif(Debt!B:B, B7, Debt!H:H)

Here is what I have so far:

```
 Dim lr As Long
  Dim lra As Long
lr = Sheets("Summary - Debt > 12 Months").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lra = Sheets("debt").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Summary - Debt > 12 Months").Range("H7:h" & lr).Formula = "=SUMif(sheet6!b2:b" & lra,(sheet5!b7:b" & lr),(Sheet6!h2:h" & lra))"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
    Dim lr As Long
      Dim lra As Long

lr = Sheets("Summary - Debt > 12 Months").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    lra = Sheets("debt").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Summary - Debt > 12 Months").Range("H7:h" & lr).Formula = "=SUMif(Debt!$b$2:$b$" & lra & ",b7,(Debt!$h$2:$h$" & lra & "))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your last line to a string variable (say sTest) and the use the immediate window Ctrl + G and type ?sTest

What you are trying to pass will not be what you think it is.

You need more &'s and starting quotes.

```
Sheets("Summary - Debt > 12 Months").Range("H7:h" & lr).Formula = "=SUMif(sheet6!b2:b" & lra & ",(sheet5!b7:b" & lr & "),(Sheet6!h2:h" & lra & "))"
```

Comment: Hi,  Still not working.  The result is =SUMIF(Sheet6!B2:B8670,(B7),(Sheet6!H2:H8670)). The workbook does not have a sheet named Sheet6, but rather Debt...

Comment: Then, that's part of your problem...your code says sheet6

Comment: @Rdster the PO is using the `Sheet6` as Sheet's index inside the workbook. He actualy means the sheet that is named `Debt` (read his post again). just modify `sheet` to `Debt` in your answer and it should work. And also `Sheet5` to `Summary - Debt > 12 Months`

Comment: Yup, I understand that.  I as going to allow him to have the Eureka! moment when he put that together for himself.